# Sharing urls containing # with facebook, twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, http, twitter

Is it possible to share the following links with facebook and twitter

```
http://www.somedomain.com/something#param
```

The problem is that when you share such links `#param` is cut so that you share `http://www.somedomain.com/something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to replace # with %23. That will allow you to share links with hash.

Answer (score 0):

Change your hash to a query string and it will be compatible with both twitter and facebook sharing.  Of course this will take some work on the server to redirect the user's browser then to the url with the hash.